# PHPMailer: blocked by Strato hosting?

Tags: php, email, localhost, hosting, phpmailer

After having spent endless hours reading and trying different solutions, and checked the topics in StackOverflow related to PHPMailer, I am giving up... I hope someone could help me on this, I would really appreciate it.

I am using PHPMailer to send an automatic email when the user requests it via a form.

## CASES

These are the different scenarios that I am facing:

**A) From Localhost** -> Everything works

1. PHPMailer in Localhost sending an email from a gmail account (smtp.gmail.com) to the user -> **WORKS**
2. Same, but from a hotmail account (smtp.live.com) -> **WORKS**

**B)** Exactly the same folders/files uploaded into my **Strato hosting space**:

1. From the same gmail account that worked in the localhost -> The webpage freezes
2. From the same hotmail account that worked in the localhost -> The webpage freezes
3. From a Strato email account (smtp.strato.com) -> **WORKS**

When I say that the webpage freezes, I refer to the fact that the wepage keeps loading forever without showing any kind of error, despite having the option **SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER** activated, so that, it is very difficult to debug.
Actually, when that happens, the whole website gets irresponsive for (roughly) a couple of minutes.

## ADDITIONAL INFO

PHP Version 7.3
PHPMailer Compatible with PHP >= 5.5
PHPMailer **troubleshooting from GitHub**-> I checked the whole list except the actions related to certificates, as I did not find the way to do it.
**Stackoverflow** -> I went through the whole list of PHPMailer-related topics. I did not find the solution.

**Some especific actions that I tried** suggested in the troubleshooting:

- Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com')
- I tried both PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS and PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS
- Ports: 465 for ssl, 587 for tls, 25 and 2525.
- check that openssl extension is enabled

**UPDATE 6th Oct 2020**
Strato has clarified that they do not block these kind of requests, hence, the initial guess is not the cause.

> **Reasonable guess?**
> This is telling me that Strato might be blocking my website from
> requesting to external servers, however, I am not a professional of
> this, so this is just a logical guess.

Many thanks to you all in advance.
If I missed the solution somewhere, please do feel free to just redirct me to the article/site.
Thanks!

## CODE

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
ini_set('display_errors', true);

require_once '../vendor/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require_once '../vendor/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require_once '../vendor/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
if (extension_loaded('openssl')) {
    echo 'openssl extension loaded.';}

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->CharSet =  "utf-8";
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                  
$mail->Username='xxxxx';
$mail->Password = "xxxxx";
$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
$mail->SMTPOptions = [
    'ssl' => [
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    ]
    ];
//$mail->Host = "smtp.strato.com";
//$mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

// set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Port = "587";
$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
$mail->From='xxxxxx@gmail.com';
$mail->FromName='xxxx';
$mail->AddAddress($email, '');
$mail->Subject  =  'some text';
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Body    = 'more text';
// *************************** The server hangs right here ***********************
if($mail->Send())
{
    echo "nice";
}
else
{
    echo "Mail Error - >".$mail->ErrorInfo;
}
?>
```

Comment: _"This is telling me that Strato might be blocking..."_ - You should start by asking them about it so you know if there's any point to debug this at all. If they are blocking it, they probably have some other way for you to send emails. In general, if you have questions about a specific service, always start by contacting the service provider.

Comment: Hi @MagnusEriksson, thanks for your answer. Absolutely, that is the first thing that I did. I am awaiting for an answer from the hosting provider. However, as I am not expert, I wanted to make sure that I was not making an evident mistake somewhere. In any case I will give an update as soon as they answer me. Many thanks

Comment: Yep, this looks exactly like they block all SMTP except to their own servers. This is what GoDaddy does too. It’s not “freezing”, it’s that the SMTP connect timeout is 10 minutes, so that’s how long it will wait. This is why SMTP is unsuited to remote connections during synchronous page requests, and why you should relay through a local or nearby server that can do the waiting for you.

Comment: **UPDATE**: First of all, thanks for your replies. Strato claims that they do not block these requests at all. I will try to find the way of providing more useful info such as error codes and so on.